# JS: Adding form field data, total won't display

Tags: javascript, html

I'm calculating total marks using form fields and a JS function.

The problem is the total of the calculation won't display and I'm not sure what the problem is, whether it's the syntax or button. I've tried another type of button, but it still isn't working.

**My code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img { background-color: grey;
      margin:0;
}

h2 { text-align : center;
     font : bold;
     }
#bod1 { margin: auto;
}

table {  margin: auto;
    width: 48%;
    padding: 3px;
}

#tr1{ margin : 0;
}

td1{ padding:2px;
}
</style>
<script>

function lol()
{
  var hot1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('HOT1Marks').value);
  var hot2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('HOT2Marks').value);
  var assignment = parseInt(document.getElementById('AssgMarks').value);
  var miniproject = parseInt(document.getElementById('MiniPMarks').value);
  var finalexam = parseInt(document.getElementById('FinalMarks').value);
  var Total = parseInt(hot1 + hot2 + assignment + miniproject + finalexam);
  document.getElementById('TotalMarks').value)=Total;
}

</script>

</head>

<body>
<table>
<form action"">

<tr>
<td colspan="2"></td>
<td>Name : <input type="text" name="name"></td>
<td>Student ID : <input type="text" name="studentid"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Assessment Type</td>
<td><b>Total percentage</td>
<td><b>Total marks</td>
<td><b>Your marks</td>
<td><b>Percentage</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td id="tr1" style=><b>HOT #1: </td>
<td><b>15%</td>
<td><b>60</td>
<td><input type="text" id="HOT1Marks"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>HOT #2: </td>
<td><b>10%</td>
<td><b>80</td>
<td><input type="text" id="HOT2Marks"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Assignment:</td>
<td><b>5%</td>
<td><b>30</td>
<td><input type="text" id="AssgMarks"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Mini Project:</td>
<td><b>30%</td>
<td><b>60</td>
<td><input type="text" id="MiniPMarks"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Final Exam:</td>
<td><b>40%</td>
<td><b>100</td>
<td><input type="text" id="FinalMarks"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2"></td>
<td><b>Total Marks:</td>
<td><input type="text" id="TotalMarks"></td>
</tr>



<tr>

<td><input type="submit" value="Process" onclick="lol()"></td>
<td><input type="reset" value="Reset"></td>
</tr>


</form>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: What happens if you change the .value to .val()  :)

Comment: @Creator You'd get `val() is undefined` because the OP isn't using JQuery. ;)

Comment: `document.getElementById('TotalMarks').value=Total;`
There is an extra `)` after value.

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML so we can reproduce your issue and give you some guidance.

Comment: @jdope You should still update your question with the appropriate code and supply an edit that explains what the problem was. You do this for others that will come along in the future and read this.

Answer (score 0):

Your primary issue is an extra `)` in the last line of your JS:

```
.value)=
```

This is stopping your JS from fully loading, and thus the browser isn't running your function `lol()`.

Beyond this, here are more issues as well:

- Since you're manually processing your form with JS, you need to override the default submit action of the form. You could capture and override the submit event in JS, but it's easier to just explicitly set your button `<input>` (or `<button>`) as `type="button"` rather than `type="submit"`. Ultimately, since you're processing your form in JS, you'll also submit it in JS when all conditions pass.
- Although convenient, using `onclick` in a button to run a JS function is highly discouraged. It's much better to create a listener for your button in JS, and run a function accordingly. There are plenty of old discussions about this.
- Clean up your HTML a bit. Remove any empty `action=` or `style=` from your elements in HTML.
- When processing the form, if any field is blank (or not numeric input), this will result in an error ("NaN") when attempting to add up all your fields. As a starting point, perhaps all fields should be a default "0" hidden value. In any case, confirming field data type is one of many checks you should be building into this form.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/MarsAndBack/pen/axBKxd)

```js
function lol() {
  console.log("Processing");
  var hot1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('HOT1Marks').value);
  var hot2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('HOT2Marks').value);
  var assignment = parseInt(document.getElementById('AssgMarks').value);
  var miniproject = parseInt(document.getElementById('MiniPMarks').value);
  var finalexam = parseInt(document.getElementById('FinalMarks').value);
  var Total = parseInt(hot1 + hot2 + assignment + miniproject + finalexam);
  document.getElementById('TotalMarks').value = Total;
}

document.getElementById ("button_process").addEventListener ("click", lol, false);
```

```css
img {
  background-color: grey;
  margin:0;
}

h2 {
  text-align : center;
  font : bold;
}

#bod1 {
  margin: auto;
}

table {
  margin: auto;
  width: 48%;
  padding: 3px;
}

#tr1 {
  margin : 0;
}

td1 {
  padding:2px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  
<form>

<tr>
<td colspan="2"></td>
<td>Name : <input type="text" name="name"></td>
<td>Student ID : <input type="text" name="studentid"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Assessment Type</td>
<td><b>Total percentage</td>
<td><b>Total marks</td>
<td><b>Your marks</td>
<td><b>Percentage</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td id="tr1" style=><b>HOT #1: </td>
<td><b>15%</td>
<td><b>60</td>
<td><input type="text" id="HOT1Marks"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>HOT #2: </td>
<td><b>10%</td>
<td><b>80</td>
<td><input type="text" id="HOT2Marks"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Assignment:</td>
<td><b>5%</td>
<td><b>30</td>
<td><input type="text" id="AssgMarks"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Mini Project:</td>
<td><b>30%</td>
<td><b>60</td>
<td><input type="text" id="MiniPMarks"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Final Exam:</td>
<td><b>40%</td>
<td><b>100</td>
<td><input type="text" id="FinalMarks"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2"></td>
<td><b>Total Marks:</td>
<td><input type="text" id="TotalMarks"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><button type="button" id="button_process">Process</input>
    </td>
  <td><button type="reset" id="button_reset">Reset</button></td>
</tr>

</form>

</table>
```